# Use expected value of a simple number guessing game to prove binary search being the best strategy

Tags: probability, statistics

In a simple number guessing game between integers [1..n], Alice tries to guess the number that Bob is thinking:

1. If Alice is right, Bob answers "correct".
2. If Alice's guess is too big, Bob answers "too big".
3. If Alice's guess is too small, Bob answers "too small".

Alice keep trying until Bob answers "correct". Each step's cost is 1.

This is a simple binary search algorithm. However, how can I formulate the expected value of each step E(n,k): "the expected value of selecting 1 <= k <= n" and eventually derived that "using k=n/2 (binary search) in each step is the best strategy among all possible selections of k, and takes only lg(n) steps ?

Comment: Since Bob picks a number [presumably] using a uniform probability distribution, the best guess at any time is one which halves the probability mass because there is an equal probability that Alice's guess will be larger or smaller. This is generalizable to any probability distribution if the words 'half' and 'equal probability' are appropriately changed.

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation. It will be nicer if there is a more formal proof with a formula so that I can tweak the weight of the formula a bit if the cost function of Alice's answer changed instead of always 1, and then use min_of_k( E(n,k) ) to determine the best strategy. I failed to formulate one even with this most basic cost function with constant "1" only :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let each step's cost be whatever. It doesn't matter (as long as it is positive) because you're going to have to take it at every step anyway. Thus the problem is now to minimize the number of steps. We make the reasonable assumption that the expected number of steps is increasing with $n$.

We assume Bob's number is *uniformly* randomly distributed in the integers in $[1, n]$. If Alice guesses a number $k$ in this interval, the chance that it is too small is $\frac{n - k}{n}$, that of it being too big is $\frac{k - 1}{n}$, and that of it being correct is $\frac1n$. If it is correct, we stop.

Otherwise, the expected number of numbers left after an incorrect guess $k$ is $n-k$ with probability $\frac{n - k}{n}$ and $k-1$ with probability $\frac{k - 1}{n}$, which is
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{(n-k)^2 + (k-1)^2}{n} &= \frac{n^2 + 2k^2 + 1 - 2k(n + 1)}{n} \\
&= \frac{2(k - \frac{n + 1}{2})^2 + \frac{(n-1)^2}{2}}{n}
\end{align*}$$
A larger value here means more expected steps because of our 'increasing cost' assumption, so we want to minimize this, which leads to the choice of $k = \frac{n+1}{2}$ (with rounding because these are integers).

Thus we choose approximately the middle integer, and repeat the process with no changes at all. Proving the expected number of steps is $\log_2 n$ is easy from here.

---

Let's relax the assumption that Bob's choice is uniformly randomly distributed, and instead take a probability distribution over integers $P(x)$. The expected number of numbers, including the case of a correct guess, is then
$$(k - 1)\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} P(i)\, +\, P(k)\, +\, (n - k)\sum_{i=k+1}^n P(i)$$
This may have different minimum points, but the principle is the same. Again, the cost of each step does not matter as long as it is positive. (If it was negative, you'd want to maximize the number of steps so that you earn instead of trying to guess correctly...)

Comment: Wow! This is brilliant, thanks for the beautiful answer!